# Do I need to use locks when using threads in this python program?

Tags: python

I created a class like this to create threads using threading module of python.

```
class myThread(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, threadID, func,param):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.threadID = threadID
    self.func = func
    self.param= param

  def run(self):
    self.result=self.func(self.param)

  def join(self):
    threading.Thread.join(self)
    return self.result
```

then I use

```
def func(x):
        print(x)
        return x

threadID=0
global threads
threads=[]
params={'start':5}
for i in range(5):
        tempParams=copy.deepcopy(params)
        t=myThread(threadID,func,tempParams)
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
        threadFileNames[threadID]=fileName
        threadStart[threadID]=start
        threadEnd[threadID]=end
        threadID+=1
for t in threads:
        print(t.join())
```

Do I need to use `threading.lock()` anywhere? I am running this code and sometimes it runs smoothly but sometimes it just keeps on running and I have to `Ctrl-C`.

Comment: What is `func`?

Comment: func is a function which can be anything. Even print or any arbitrary function.

Comment: That looks like you just want `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool()` instead.